# python random sum quiz

Tags: python, if-statement

i am writing a program in school for a certain task in which 10 random questions will be output, each time prompting the user for an answer. below is the code i have worked on so far:

```
from random import randint

rand1 = (randint(0,12))
rand2 = (randint(0,12))

signlist = ["x", "+", "-"]

print(rand1, signlist[randint(0,2)], rand2)
result = input("what is the answer to the sum above? ")

if result == rand1+rand2 or result == rand1-rand2 or result ==rand1*rand2:
    print ("correct")
else:
    print ("incorrect")
```

regardless on whether or not the user inputs the correct answer, the program outputs "incorrect".

is it due to the 'or' function? am i using it incorrectly?
or does anyone suggest completely rewriting the code (if it is that inaccurate  )

i was also having trouble using 'return' within my *if* statement, as the following error message occurred:

> 'return' outside function.

why is this error message showing when 'print' is replaced with return?

Comment: you need to convert the input to an integer. also your code will accept 6 as correct for "3 - 2" and 12 as correct for "6 * 6" for example

Comment: I suggest there should be a canonical question for the "my Python math quiz homework doesn't work" question. Possible duplicate of [a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455047/python-arithmetic-quiz-task-1), [b](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33232374/how-do-i-check-if-the-user-has-entered-a-number), [c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33221287/creating-a-quiz-in-python-error), [d](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33178117/whats-wrong-with-my-code-invalid-syntax) ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> regardless on whether or not the user inputs the correct answer, the program outputs "incorrect".

It tried a few time and got the *correct* output. However, I don't think the following behavior is accepted, right?

```
rand1 = 3
rand2 = 4
signlist = '+'
```

`result = 7` works, as well as `result = 12` and `result = -1`.

You should check the result depending of `signlist`:

```
from random import randint

rand1 = (randint(0,12))
rand2 = (randint(0,12))

signlist = ["x", "+", "-"]

print "%s %s %s" % (rand1, signlist[randint(0,2)], rand2)
result = input("what is the answer to the sum above? ")

if (signlist == "x" and result == rand1*rand2) or (signpost == "+" and result == rand1+rand2) or (signlist == "-" and result == rand1-rand2):
    print "correct"
else:
    print "incorrect"
```

> why is this error message showing when 'print' is replaced with return?

Because you're not allowed to return something. When you use `print`, you don't return anything, you just *print* something, and this is accepted.

Comment: I am quite inexperienced with "or" & "and" functions, clearly.They were only briefly explained to our class last week before having this task thrust our way. Thank you very much for the help, Yuriko. Although, I have just ran your code 4 times, still to be output "incorrect" all four times. The formatter %s also seemed to be causing trouble as well, bring up an "invalid syntax" error

Comment: After a bit of editing, its working. Brilliant. Thank you very much!

Comment: [*and*, *or* are not functions, they are operators.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm "Tutorialspoint - Python Basic Operators")